# Control System For Sensor Networks

Tags: networking, sensors, distributed-system

I'm making a distributed sensor network.  The basic architecture of my network is to have several slave nodes (up to about 10) reporting back to a master node on a regular basis.

I'm looking for a software framework that I can use for this, so far I have thought of

- corba
- pubsubhubub
- xmtp
- making my own

I have some basic requirements (like basic security, fault awareness)

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: +1 Interesting question :) How familiar are you with sensor networks and kit already?

Comment: Well, the sensors are just about complete, I just need a way to control then and them combine the data.

Answer (score 0):

In specific answer to your question, [TinyOS](http://www.tinyos.net/) provides a lot of what you'll need.

There's quite a large body of academic work on getting these up and running, especially combining agent-based infrastructures with sensor networks -- take a look on [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=agent+sensor+network&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) for example.

There are also some very good links on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_sensor_network).

Are you specifically interested in an OS to run on your sensors, or something at higher level that plugs into some sensor infra you already have? Are you intending to build your own kit, or work on something that already exists (e.g. [BTNode](http://www.btnode.ethz.ch/))?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RL-ARM or FreeRTOS if you wanted to use micro controllers for your project. also in the network layer you can use lwip.
there are many other libraries both free and open source in case if you want to use ARM based micro controllers.